# Standard deviation of a cartesian distance calculated using the haversine in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, variance, haversine, uncertainty

I have four matlab vectors which denote the position of two airplanes using Shperical coordinates at different moments. I have calculated the distance between them using the [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) as

```
haversine_angle=(sin((phiMeanA-phiMeanB)/2)).^2+cos(lambdaMeanA).*cos(lambdaMeanB).*

(sin((lambdaMeanA-lambdaMeanB)/2)).^2;
    
 haversine_sqrt=(haversine_angle).^0.5;
 haversine_sqrt2=1.-haversine_sqrt;

 RT=6378*1000;
    
 haversine_mean_distance =RT.*atan2(haversine_sqrt, haversine_sqrt2);
```

I also have four aditional vectors which contain the values of the standard deviation associated to `phiMeanA, phiMeanB, lambdaMeanA` and `lambdaMeanB`, so, I would like to calculate the standard deviation of `haversine_mean_distance`, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would suggest to use a bootstrap approach here

Comment: Note: When `haversine_angle` is close to 1, `haversine_sqrt2` loses lots of precession, causing wide swings for `haversine_mean_distance`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to do it using [this propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) using phimeanA, phiMeanB, lambdameanA and lambdaMeanB as x, y, z and t.